# Running the same code multiple times causes a primary key constraint error

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have some SSIS packages that both call a package called `Refresh Exchange Rates` before they load because those other packages are reliant on exchange rates being refreshed.

The Exchange Rate table has primary key constraints to prevent duplicate entries. Sometimes, the `Refresh Exchange Rates` package will run multiple times at once as multiple packages is calling the same code. The following is the code that runs, however it produces a primary key constraint when run multiple times:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.FactExchangeRate
INSERT INTO dbo.FactExchangeRate (
  FromCurrencyId,
  ToCurrencyId,
  RateDate,
  ExchangeRate
) 
SELECT
  FromDimCurrency.Id AS FromCurrencyId,
  ToDimCurrency.Id AS ToCurrencyId,
  CAST(AXCURD.DT AS DATE) AS RateDate,
  AXCURD.EXRATE AS ExchangeRate
FROM
  DataWarehouseRawData.dbo.AXCURD
INNER JOIN
  dbo.DimCurrency FromDimCurrency ON
  FromDimCurrency.SourceKey = AXCURD.FRAXCURIDX
INNER JOIN
  dbo.DimCurrency ToDimCurrency ON
  ToDimCurrency.SourceKey = AXCURD.TOAXCURIDX
```

What can I do to prevent this?
I'm aware the code is running multiple times (3 times in this instance), so I'm guessing this is something to do with transactions etc.

I've tried using a `TABLOCKX` on the insert, change the `TRUNCATE` to a `DELETE` (for transactions) and also tried a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` etc but that ultimately caused a deadlock.

Comment: Rather than a TRUNCATE/INSERT pattern use a INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE pattern or a MERGE command. In general this is a better idea than truncate/insert, especially in a datawarehouse. For example right now you probably can't create foreign keys in your data warehouse because they would fail the load process. If you want more info let me know

Comment: Most of our dimensions are merged however this is one of our facts that we truncate and reload as it's a quick process. We purposely don't have any foreign keys. Can you explain why a merge would help my issue? Isn't a merge really just syntactic sugar for a dml operation?

Comment: A merge won't insert a record that already exists.. in theory but since you have multiple sessions doing it I'm not too sure. Personally I prefer seperate INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements to MERGE because apparently it has some bugs (which might now be fixed). A more 'fundamental' solution would be to turn on snapshot isolation, then use transactions, which means while your table is locked inside a transaction, anything else uses the version of the table that existed before without getting locked.

Comment: Do you purposely have no foreign keys for this reason only? FK's are good things!

Comment: Here's my favourite article on snapshot isolation which I had to read at least a dozen times to understand. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid- In a data warehouse, they can severely slow things down and as long as your ETL process is rock solid, they are unncecessary. I'll have a read of that article! I knew I needed some change to the isolation level but wasn't sure which. I will report back!

Comment: FK's can also speed things up on the read side and that's what you want. So just like an index you can add it afterwards. They definitely severely slow down deletes. It's a database support structure just like an index that may or may not give the query planner a useful hint. But yes I hear you - sometimes the advantages are outweighed by the maintenance and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just need to space out your timing so that the packages aren't running on top of each other. Are these packages configured under one sql server job or are there multiple jobs? If the latter, try scheduling the jobs 5-10 mins apart to give each job time to complete. And if all your packages are under one job then split the packages into separate job steps and make sure the steps run in sequential order.

Comment: That is not a solution to the problem! You may as well say run it once a week on a Sunday morning when nobody is on the system...

Comment: @ BIDeveloper: Stunshaw's answer could be a solution. We had the same case a while ago. Our SQL-Server ran into resource deadlocks all the time. The reason was that the jobs all started at the same time. btw: Do not ridicule others just because you never had the problem and therefore cannot connect the dots. You're just ridiculing yourself

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to insert OR update depending on whether the data already exists.

[SSIS - Insert new rows, update rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227655/ssis-insert-new-rows-update-rows)